# Changing the permissions in root files without sudo from recovery

Tags: root, data-recovery, chmod, etc

Hi I recently killed my etc folder by running:

```
sudo chmod etc 417.
```

Due to sudo being in that folder it cannot be accesed now, so I have to change the permissions back to the correct ones using the recovery menu.

In recovery i tried this from recovery:

```
root@joeri-VirtualBox:/# chmod 755 etc
chmod: changing permissions of 'etc' : read-only file system
root@joeri-VirtualBox:/# cd etc
root@joeri-VirtualBox:/etc# ls -ld
drw-rw-rwx 139 root root 12288 2012-04-19 16:29
```

Even when I am root i cannot change it because it is read-only.
How do I change these permissions?

Thanks

Joeri.

Comment: This: `sudo chmod etc 417.` is not a valid instruction. It will end up with an error message **invalid mode etc**. Might be needed to include the exact command that was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remount the root file system with read/write permissions if you want to do changes in recovery mode `mount -o remount,rw /` I think is the command. Then you can modify the filesystem.